# How can I perform a Google search on different Google datacentres?

Tags: seo

I would like to get up-to-date information on Google's index of a website, and it seems
that results vary depending on which datacentre happens to process your search query.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a violation of google's TOS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the many tools designed specifically for this. One of them is [Google Datacenter Search at iWebTool](http://www.iwebtool.com/google_datacenter_search).

(It's really all about getting a list of data center IPs and sending the same GET variable to them as to google.com.)

Comment: Great! I see that I am limited to 5 searches per hour. Are there any other limitations, for example can I use this every day?

Comment: It looks like manually inserting the IP address into the address bar is the simplest solution once you have gathered them.